# Java create unique thread per database row

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the requirement to poll the database every x seconds and pull out records that need to be processed.  I will start a thread for each of these rows.  The next time I poll the threads may not have completed yet.  I don't want to start another thread for the same ID as it is still processing.

A `HashMap<String, Callable>` seems appropriate for storing the threads and ensuring that only one thread per ID will exist .  What I can't figure out is how do I remove the thread after the thread is done?

My understanding is that if I wait on the thread then it will be blocking the main thread and the polling will not continue.

I have tried the following code and it works, but the HashMap will continue to grow as more tasks come in.  There is a possibility that the row could be reprocessed later in the day.

```
HashMap<String, Callable<String>> callables = new HashMap<String, Callable<String>>();
for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(int j =0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        String key = Integer.toString(j);
        if(!callables.containsKey(key))
        {
            callables.put(key, new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Inside task");
                    return "Task Completed";
                }
            });
            try
            {
                callables.get(key).call();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Task skipped: " + j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why convert the integer to a string?  Why not just use the integer as the key?  What are the double loops for?

Comment: I was contriving an example that would help illustrate the problem.  My actual key will be a string.  The double loop is to demonstrate that the next time through the "key" would not be processed again

Comment: You  need a thread pool. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: What is the mechanism by which I can get notified that the thread is done without blocking the main thread?

Comment: You also need to forget about thread and use Executor/ThreadPool, etc

Comment: This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Once a record has been successfully completed how does the next run not select that completed record?  Is there a status column on the record so the query is something like select ... where status = 'PENDING'?  When records are selected, update their status to "PROCESSING".  This way it won't matter if polling happens to overlap.  And don't create a new thread for every row.  Just create a task for each row and submit to an ExecutorService.

Comment: Tip: don't create a thread per record. What do you think happens if you have 1000 rows, or 10000, or a million?

Comment: Worst, what happens if the app goes down after processing some number of rows?  Does the next instance of the app start over from the beginning?  Is that correct?

Comment: This example is contrived in order to show the problem.  I am adding controls to how many threads get started, checkpoints in the database to show where in the process it is, retry logic, etc.  @Andrew I do use the database to control the status of the row.  Trying to avoid race condition between the thread changing the status and the next polling cycle.

Comment: I don't see a race condition: 1) **main** thread polls for records, 2) **main** thread updates the status of those records to "PROCESSING", 3) a task (or tasks) is submitted to process those records.  See also: SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.

Comment: @AndrewS I see what you saying.  Good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is to remove the couple (key, Callable) from your Map when the thread has finished its job. Call remove() at the end of its call() function.

```
HashMap<String, Callable<String>> callables = new HashMap<String, 
Callable<String>>();
for(int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j =0; j < 10; j++) {
        String key = Integer.toString(j);
        if(!callables.containsKey(key)) {
            callables.put(key, new Callable<String>() {
                final String mKey = key; //store the current key
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Inside task");
                    callables.remove(mKey); //Remove the thread from the Map
                    return "Task Completed";
                }
            });
            try {
                callables.get(key).call();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Task skipped: " + j);
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting.  I didn't think you were allowed to access items outside the lambda.  I am not seeing how do you get key into mKey?

Comment: @RichardBinnington Edited to add key in mKey

Comment: Thank you sir!  I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `Callable`s inside your own `Callable`.

```
HashMap<String, Callable<String>> callables = new HashMap<>();

public void oneOnly(String id, Callable<String> callable) {
    if (!callables.containsKey(id)) {
        // Wrap the callable in my own.
        callables.put(id, new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                String result = callable.call();
                // Remove when finished.
                callables.remove(id);
                return result;
            }
        });

    }
}

public void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            String key = Integer.toString(j);
            oneOnly(key, new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Inside task");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return "Task Completed";
                }
            });
            try {
                callables.get(key).call();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```